# Create a vertical timeline with bullet in css

Tags: css

I am trying to create a vertical timeline having [this codepen](https://codepen.io/Rpx89/pen/abwOOKO) as reference but unfortunately it's not working for me.

My code is here in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-bush-nfglx?file=/src/styles.module.css)

`App.js`

```
import styles from "./styles.module.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className={styles.carouselContentWrapper}>
        <div className={styles.year}>
          <span>2021</span>
        </div>
        <ul className={styles.textWrapper}>
          <li className={styles.text1}>Text1</li>
          <li className={styles.text2}>Text2</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`Styles.module.css`

```
.textWrapper ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 6px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background: #fff;
}

.textWrapper ul li::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: inherit;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Any ideas on what is causing this would be much appreciated.

Note: Just to mention that I am using css modules in my original project so would like it to work by using css modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put text in div so you can position it:

```css
.textWrapper ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 6px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background: #fff;
}
.textWrapper ul li::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: inherit;
  z-index: -1;
}
.textWrapper ul li div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 25px;
  color: white;
}
body {
  background-color: blueviolet
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class={styles.carouselContentWrapper}>
    <div class={styles.year}>
      <span>2021</span>
    </div>
    <div class=textWrapper>
      <ul>
        <li class={styles.text}>
          <div>Text1</div>
        </li>
        <li class={styles.text}>
          <div>Text2</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it works as reference codepan. give background color to your ul or change for li.